# How to appropriately suggest title changes?

Tags: discussion, edits, title

Recently I answered a question that deals with a very common problem.  After reading the question title again I realized that very few people would express the question the same way as the person who asked it.  Therefore it would be hard for others to find it and its answers.

Is there a way to suggest a new title for a question?

Comment: Kudos to Gnome for the title change :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit the title, or leave a comment.

Comment: (I wasn't aware that with 2000 rep you can edit titles as well.)

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the title yourself if you have 2000 rep points (which you don't), leave a comment asking for such an edit, or maybe even flag the post for moderator attention, explaining your reason.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage contacting a moderator to edit the title. Not unless the title is offensive, or inappropriate in some way. If you decide to do this, please make it your last option.

Comment: Agreed, flagging for attention should not be used a substitute for simply not having enough rep to edit.  There's a reason such changes are limited to those more familiar with the site that have also helpfully contributed (as judged by the community).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I'm pro edits only for the reasons of:
1. correcting grammar  / punctuation / and the like (like that one blank between punctuation that everyone freaks about).
2. correcting it in a way that it adds extra info

All other, in general, no.

Comment: I am *way* more likely to edit a post to make it clearer to the reader before I start fixing grammar, punctuation, etc (unless it just  incomprehensible). But, as long as I already editing, *then* I'll fix up the incidentals.

Comment: @Robert ... - all right, but how do you know you're doing it right ? I've seen cases where the content was edited in a way that the new one didn't correspond to the meaning of the old one ... not to my understanding of the old one, at least. So it is somewhat subjective, is it not ?

Comment: It is subjective, to a point. If you change meaning or context, **it's a bad edit**. But I have many, many years of technical copy editing experience and it becomes easier to notice when "Oof, this would be *much* clearer if you used *this* word (or said it *this* way)." But my point was that I generally *don't* do simple *remove-that-one-blank* -type edits unless it is accompanied with changes making the post clearer. That's just me, though. I *want* to correct everyone's spelling/grammar but it just *feels* somehow "wrong." I *don't* fault those who do it, though. More power to you, really.